# For a dictionary compare both key and value with the values in a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have the following structures:

```
prev = { 'alpha:10.2': '145', 'teta:180': '198', 'eltira:140': '222', 'ronta:23.14':220}
now = ['alpha:10.3','teta:180', 'eltira:142']
```

and the following code:

```
   old = []
    for k, v in prev.iteritems():
     if k not in now:
       old.append(v)
```

So if the key from the dict `prev` is not found in the list `now`, I add the value to the `old` list.

Result 'old= [ '145', '222']`

But, I want to check also which part doesn't correspond from the key. I'm inclined to use namedtuple.

```
Package = collections.namedtuple('Package', 'name version')

for k, v in prev.items():
  name, version = k.split(':')
  Package(name=k, version='v')
```

1. if the `name` corresponds but the `version` not, do the same as above.
2. if the `name` is not found add it to a new list `old_names`, but also do as above.

The issue is that `if k not in now` will not work. I can do it with two loops and three `ifs` but maybe there is an option to do it more clean.

Expecting output:

`old=[ '145', '222']`
`old_names=['ronta']`

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have splitted the 'now' list and converted it to a dictionary (name:version) which takes a single iteration. Later, the values from the dictionary can be accessed in constant time for further operations.

```
prev = { 'alpha:10.2': '145', 'teta:180': '198', 'eltira:140': '222', 'old:1. 43':'150'}
now = ['alpha:10.3','teta:180', 'eltira:142']

now_dict = {}
old = []
old_names = []

for items in now:
  temp0,temp1 = items.split(':')
  now_dict[temp0] = temp1

for k,v in prev.items():
   name,version = k.split(':')
   if name not in now_dict.keys():
      old_names.append(name)
      old.append(v)
      continue

   if version != now_dict[name]:
      old.append(v)
      continue

   else:
     continue

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print(old_names)
  print(old)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it:

```py
prev = { 'alpha:10.2': '145', 'teta:180': '198', 'eltira:140': '222', 'zeta:12.1' : '334'}
now = ['alpha:10.3','teta:180', 'eltira:142']

now_splited = [nk.split(":") for nk in now]

old = []
old_name = []
for k, v in prev.items():
    if k not in new_key:
        old_n, old_v = k.split(":")
        name = any(map(lambda n : n[0] == old_n, now_splited))
        version = any(map(lambda n : n[1] == old_v, now_splited))
        if name and not version:
            old.append(v)
        elif not name:
            old_name.append(old_n
            old.append(old_v))
```

Results :

```py
>>> print(old, old_name)
['145', '222', '334'] ['zeta']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `now` a dict by `map`ing `operator.methodcaller` to it and wrapping it in `dict()` then a comprehension will be easy using the same method on prev:

```
splitter = operator.methodcaller('split', ':')
now_dict, kv_map = dict(map(splitter, now)), map(splitter, prev)

old = [prev[':'.join((k,v))] for k, v in kv_map if k in now_dict]
old_names = [n for n, v in kv_map if n not in now_dict]
```

Results:

```
#old
['145', '198', '222']
#old_names
[]
```